# Cauchy's functional equation over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that for $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)$ that if $f$ is surjective then $f(x)=\pm x$. I've tried using the fact that $f(0)=0$ and that for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ : $f(am)=af(m)$ but it didn't really yield anything but circular arguments. My intuition is that since $f$ is defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ the function can only return all whole numbers is if $f(x)=\pm x$, but how do I know that f must be linear in the first place? I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d = f(1)$ Then we have

$f(2) = f(1)+f(1)=2d$

$f(3)= f(1+1+1) = 3d$

and so on. We also have

$0 = f(0) = f(1 - 1) =f(1)+f(-1)$

so $f(-1)=-f(1) = -d$, and as above $f(-2)=-2d$ and so on. In total we get

$f(n)=dn$

What values of $d$ makes $f$ surjective?